# "We are looking for long answers ..." on a question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, post-notice

[This question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1973/remove-last-comma-problem) has been marked with the text

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

From the text I would assume that should be attached to an answer and never on a question.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

It is as intended.  The same message can apply to questions too, as a pre-emptive warning to anyone wanting to write an answer.

Unfortunately, the question is rather old, and the rule that you must review the code wasn't strictly applied at the time.  We're doing our best to raise the standards despite past mistakes.